# why is my fetch API not working on my next.js project

Tags: typescript, next.js, fetch

```
import { GetServerSideProps } from 'next';

type Product = { //Product variables
  id: number;
  title: string;
  price: number;
  thumbnail: string;
};

interface ProductsProps {
  products: Product[];
}

export default function Products({ products }: ProductsProps){
  return (
    <main>
      <h1 className="productHeader">Our Products</h1>
      <div className="products">
        {products && products.map((product) => (  `//mapping`
          <div className="card" key={product.id}>
            <p>{product.thumbnail}</p>          `Product info`
            <p>{product.title}</p> 
            <p>price:{product.price}$</p>
          </div>
        ))}
      </div>
    </main>
  );
};

export const getServerSideProps: GetServerSideProps = async () => {   'fetching API'
  const res = await fetch('https://dummyjson.com/products');
  const products = await res.json();

  return {
    props: {
      products,
    },
  };
};
```

i tried to fetch this('https://dummyjson.com/products') API but i cant see anything on the website the API includes Product infos like name thumbnail...
I expected to see all products on the website but it appears i did something wrong.

Comment: ...are there any errors in the terminal where you're running the next server? And does your version of node.js you're running things in actually support the fetch API without a third-party library?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using `app` router from Next.js, then `getServerSideProps` will not work.

As per Next.js 13 migration docs,

> In the app directory, we can colocate our data fetching inside our React components using Server Components. This allows us to send less JavaScript to the client, while maintaining the rendered HTML from the server.

https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/upgrading/app-router-migration#server-side-rendering-getserversideprops

---

You can fix this by converting your component to a server component, and using a fetch (that shall be rendered on your server rather than on client).

```
type Product = { //Product variables
  id: number;
  title: string;
  price: number;
  thumbnail: string;
};

async function getData() {
  const res = await fetch('https://dummyjson.com/products');
  return await res.json() as Promise<Product[]>;
};

export default async function Products(){
  const products = await getData()

  return (
    <main>
      <h1 className="productHeader">Our Products</h1>
      <div className="products">
        {products && products.map((product) => (
          <div className="card" key={product.id}>
            <p>{product.thumbnail}</p>
            <p>{product.title}</p> 
            <p>price:{product.price}$</p>
          </div>
        ))}
      </div>
    </main>
  );
};
```